# What causes linker only giving "ld returned 1 exit status" message?

Tags: linker, ld

I am using "--verbose" for ld in an attempt to get something useful for finding the problem, but it prints the error message amidst printing normal "--verbose" output:

```
[...blah - dump of linker script...]
attempt to open blah1.o succeeded
blah1.o
attempt to open blah2.o succeeded
blah2.o
[...blah - more opens that succeeded...]
attempt to open blah9.o succeeded
blah9.o
attemcollect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Invoked by:

```
gcc blah1.o [...blah...] blah9.o blahLib1.a blahLib2.a -g -lc -nostdlib -Wl,--warn-constructors -fpic -fno-pic -Wl,-q -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,--verbose -T blahScript.ld -lm -o blahProgram.elf
```

Comment: Have you found what was the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I haven't worked on that stuff since then, though, so I can't say I've been actively trying to figure out it lately. The custom script works on other people's machines, so it wasn't that. It must be something odd with my build environment.

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, I got the same problem today.  The cause was out of disk space.  In this situation "ld" seems to just return an exit code 1, with no message printed at all.  Increasing the available disk space fixed the problem.

Comment: I would never expect such weird behavior, many thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic error. Usually caused by undefined reference to a symbol.

I don't think you need --verbose to see the error. ld should print the cause of the error in any case. Try to run it without --verbose and carefully examine every line of the output.

Comment: That's the strange part - there is no other printed text whatsoever. Just the "ld returned 1 exist status".

Comment: You could try to add this option: -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all
 However, this should be default anyway. Hmm... Another thing - you're using a custom linker script (blahScript.ld). I don't know how linkers respond to errors in the script; double check the script contents.